# (Target: Object) not working for setting UIButton from outside viewController

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I can create the UIButton.
But the callback:  target: object won't work within the current object.  ??
I can only do "self.viewController" object, and can't do "self" for current object.

thx

---

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "ViewController.h"

@class ViewController;

@interface CGuiSetup : NSObject
{
    @public
    ViewController *viewController;
}
- (void) Setup;
- (void) ButtonRespond:(UIButton*) btn;
@end
```

---

```
#import "CGuiSetup.h"

@implementation CGuiSetup

- (void) ButtonRespond:(UIButton*) btn
{
    NSLog(@"ButtonRespond");
}


- (void) Setup
{

    UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,100,100)];

    // But I want to call the following in the CGuiSetup object (self) instead... but it crashes out if I leave it as just "self"
    [btn addTarget:self.viewController action:@selector(ButtonRespond:)
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; //works: for "self.viewController" if I put ButtonRespond in the ViewController

    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(ButtonRespond:)
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; //fails: for "self"

    [self.viewController.view addSubview:btn];
}
@end
```

---

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CGuiSetup.h"

@class CGuiSetup;

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    CGuiSetup *guiSetup; //<---- had to take this out of the "viewDidLoad" method
}
@end
```

---

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    guiSetup = [CGuiSetup alloc];
    guiSetup->viewController = self;


    UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,100,100)];
    [btn addTarget:guiSetup action:@selector(ButtonRespond:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:btn];

}
```

Comment: can you post the header file too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using ARC, does any object have a retaining reference to CGuiSetup?  I sounds like CGuiSetup is instantiated, creates (or maybe receives from another object) the viewController, adds the button to it and then gives the view controller to another object (perhaps by pushing it on a navController or setting it to be the root controller of the app)?  Whatever the case is, CGuiSetup it being dealloc'd and the button is trying to send a message to an object that's already been destroyed. How/where is CGuiSetup created?  What object retains a reference to it?  That's probably where your problem is.

If you don't understand what retain/release is and/or you don't know what ARC is, you need to read Apple's memory management guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html

Comment: thank you... I had to put the object as an instance variable in the ViewController class.

Comment: Do you mean the ViewController class that CGuiSetup has an an instance variable?  If so, you're going to have a retain cycle (a memory leak).  Those objects will never get dealloc'd.  That might be ok with you, but you should just be aware of it.

Comment: I added the code to show where I moved it... so from this is there a memory leak?  I would like to pull the Gui stuff out of the ViewController and put in another class.

Comment: Yes, that does create a retain cycle (memory leak). Especially under ARC, those two classes will never get dealloc'd.  Since it appears that viewController owns CGuiSetup, you'll want to consider adding __weak to the viewController iVar in CGuiSetup: `__weak ViewController *viewController;`  This will tell ARC not to retain it.  You may also want to reconsider your design.  Why does CGuiSetup need to have a reference to viewController?  Shouldn't viewController handle it's own buttons and respond to them?  Maybe, maybe not...just something to think about.

Answer (score 1):

That's probably because your object is destroyed, while _viewController still has retain count greater than 0 (so it's not destroyed). Balance you're retain/release count.

Comment: What do you mean "Balance you're retain/release count."  ?? thx

Comment: pulled out the "property" and just made it a public variable... same results for self or self.viewController.