# Adding UIButton dynamically: action not getting registered

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, hyperlink, uibutton

I'm creating pages dynamically, each page contains a Navigation Controller and UIViewController.

Inside each page, there are components like link, images, texts.

Each component is a class like the following:

```
class link: Component, ComponentProtocol {
    var text: String
    var url: String

    func browseURL(sender: UIButton!){
        let targetURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: self.url)
        let application = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
        application.openURL(targetURL!)
    }

    func generateView() -> UIView?{
        var result: UIView?
        var y = CGRectGetMinY(frame)
        var linkBtn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y:30 , width:300 , height: 50)
        linkBtn.setTitle(self.text, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        linkBtn.setTitleColor(UIColor.blueColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        linkBtn.titleLabel?.font = linkBtn.titleLabel?.font.fontWithSize(15)

        // this doesn't seem to be registered properly
        linkBtn.addTarget(self, action: "browseURL:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

        result = UIView()
        result?.addSubview(linkBtn)

        return result
}
```

Then in the ViewDidLoad of the page ViewController method I would have this to initialise the page components:

```
    for component in components!{
        if let acomponent:ComponentProtocol = component as? ComponentProtocol {
            if let res = acomponent.generateView(innerFrame) {
                if let view = res.view {
                    self.view.addSubview(view)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The button is showing, but when I touch nothing happens. When I debugged, the browseURL is no triggered at all.

What's wrong with my code? I'm guessing because I registered the action in `link` class and not in the ViewController of the page?

**UPDATE**

This could be a similar issue, but the answer is not so straightforward and I actually have the component reference in my ViewController: [(Target: Object) not working for setting UIButton from outside viewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10474914/target-object-not-working-for-setting-uibutton-from-outside-viewcontroller)

Comment: Are you using the simulator, or a mobile device?

Comment: @KickimusButticus mobile device

Answer (score 0):

I'm not at a Mac right now so I can't test, but does this work:

```
linkBtn.target = self
linkBtn.action = "browseURL:"
```

I think if you have selectors in Swift you have to be careful with colons and specifying @objc if your class doesn't inherit from NSObject, it could also be something to do with that?

Comment: I'm afraid your suggestion `linkBtn.action = "browseURL:"` is not a valid syntax. I did similar think with UIBarButtonItem. But both the UIBarButtonItem action registration and handler function are defined in the ViewController itself, and it works perfectly without @objc.